# How to create branchless code for this piece of code?

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

I need to generate branchless code for the if statement in the inner loop 
if(i != j). I am confused how to generate branchless code.

```
  for (int i = start; i < n; i++)
  {
        results[i] = 999;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                d = myfunction(x, y, i, j);
                if (d < results[i])
                    results[i] = d;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comparison returns 0 (false) or 1 (true) in C++. So you can convert the innermost condition as follows:

```
int condition = d < results[i] 
results[i] = d * condition + results[i] * !condition;
```

To skip over i in the inner loop, just add one to the arg at i and beyond:

```
...
for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
    d = myfunction(x, y, i, j + (j >= i));
    int condition = d < results[i] 
    results[i] = d * condition + results[i] * !condition;
}
...
```

An alternative with fewer comparisons would be to split the inner loop into two loops:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   ...
}
for (int j = i + i; j < n; j++) {
   ...
}
```

**Edit**: Complex increment / loop start mangling replaced.

**P.S.**: An optimizaion option might be to build the minimum in a local variable and assign to results[i] after the inner loop only.

Comment: The program will crash, suppose I have an array of size=5, when i=4, j=4 then j+=(i==j);  make j=5 this exceed index of the array.

Comment: How / why will it crash?

Comment: The loop condition is a branch, so splitting up the inner loop does reduce branching compared to putting an extra branch inside the loop body.  But it's not exactly branchless.  Some kinds of branch-prediction hardware might have predicted the loop-termination for many repeats of an `n` iteration loop, but less well for different lengths.  So it may be a wash for mispredicts, but still a win for instruction count / throughput.  (For real use I'd definitely recommend loop splitting, especially for large `n`.  The branchless way is adding a lot of work for a rare condition)

Comment: Ooops, have adjusted the loop condition to account for that

Comment: p.s. got rid of the extra assignment to j

Comment: NP. If this solves your question, you may want to accept the answer (set the checkmark), so this issue gets closed O:)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to operate on an `n` by `n` matrix, but excluding the values in a diagonal, i.e:

```
X O O O
O X O O
O O X O
O O O X
```

You could reframe the problem by "unrolling" the matrix like so:

```
. O O O
. . O O O
. . . O O O
. . . . O O O
```

Then you could correct `j` in the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // ...
    for (int j = i + 1; j < i + n; j++) {
        d = myfunction(x, y, i, j % n);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `j%n` is branchless, but slow unless the compiler transforms it into a compare/cmov instead of an actual division.  (Or if `n` is a compile-time constant, it's not bad.)  In the source, you could do `jmod++; jmod = (jmod == n) ? 0 : jmod;`

Comment: @PeterCordes: good point, incidentally, since j is bounded, we can just replace `j%n` with `j-n` to achieve the same result :D (answer updated)

Comment: Wont this make the argument negative for j < n?

Comment: Oops. Yes. this is what I get for writing the code in Python (which is happy to accept negative indices).

Comment: in this case j=i+1, j will never be zero?

Comment: I wanted to start j from zero every time the inner loop starts, but skip when i==j

Comment: Why is it important that `j` starts at zero?

Comment: because I have two one-D arrays, one array has x, other has y values from which I am calculating distance. it is necessary to start from zero every time except i==j

Comment: While it is true that `j` does not start at 0, `j % n` does “start at 0”; this code is functionally equivalent to the `if (i!=j)` case.